# "Cannot resolve symbol" in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependencies

I'm fairly new to Intellij and Java and am unable to use libraries from one "module" in another. I am seeing red class names and getting "Cannot resolve symbol ..." errors all over the place:

[image]

The other modules are referenced in File | Project Structure all the other module's Paths are correct and include the *.classes I'm trying to use:

[image]

I have also tried a File | Invalidate Caches but am still having the same problems.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add your external libraries/classes under dependencies in order for IDEA to see them when doing code analysis/autocomplete.

Comment: I've tried this but the module I'm seeing this problem in (dd4t-example site in the screenshot) isn't available in the project structure window http://i.imgur.com/ksFUFEG.png

Comment: That's because it is not a module (no blue square indicator on the icon). You either have to create a module from this folder (File > New > Module from Existing Sources) or simply add this folder as a dependency (in your module settings > dependencies click on the green + button and select "JARs or directories").

Comment: Thanks. Adding the project as a module and adding the other modules as dependencies fixed the issue.

Answer (score 24):

**Listed below are steps which may fix the problem:**

1.**Invalidate and refresh the IntelliJ's caches**

File Menu -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and restart

2.**Project SDK selection**

Check project settings from File Menu -> Project Structure
Ensure an SDK is selected for the Project SDK. If is selected, click the 'New' button, select JDK and then select the correct path to the JDK e.g. /opt/java/jdk1.8 or c:\Java\Jdk1.8

3.**Corrupt JDK**

There may be a problem with your JDK installation, re-install JDK

4.**Re-import the project**

Close the project if it is open in IntelliJ
Delete the .idea folder in the project source code folder.
Start IntelliJ and Import the project.

You can choose any of them which will work for you.

Comment: Option 4. Delete the .idea folder and rebuild the project fixed the issue for me! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I faced a similar problem for no reason, I think it was caused by IDE(android studio). I have tried all of the above solutions but not worked. Finally, in my own situation, I solved this problem by the following actions:

1. Delete your `.idea` folder in your local project.
2. Reopen this project and just let Gradle run itself.

It was worked for me. I hope that my experience will be useful for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can go to "File->Project Structure"

From "Project Settings", Select "Project" tab and there make sure that "Project SDK" has proper JDK selection.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After you add dependencies to POM file, make it a habit to refresh POM by clicking on the 'Reimports maven projects' icon. Its the first icon in the maven tool window located to the right of the main intellij editor. Its a blue icon with 2 circular arrows. Clicking it ensures that the added dependencies are fully integrated into your project

Answer (score 1):

Run it from the project's root folder.

```
$ mvn -U idea:idea
```

Comment: after using this command, the path issue resolved, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One more advise would be to make sure that you import the project properly. If it's a maven project, import pom.xml and if it's a gradle project, import gradle.build file to make sure that all the dependencies are downloaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just got this.
Just went there.
Invalidated the cache.
Seemed to work until I wrote further lines.
Then noticed that I was writing my code outside of the `main()` function.
Moved the ending curly bracket further and voila.